# do.call in r with matrix and lists

Tags: r, list, matrix

in language R, in order to generate a new matrix (N*6) as from an older one (N*3), is there a better way than the next one to do it without having to "unpack/unlist" the inner lists created in the apply function in order to "expand" the source matrix?

```
transformed <- matrix(byrow=T)
transformed <- as.matrix(
    do.call("rbind", as.list(
      apply(dataset, 1, function(x) {
         x <- list(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[2]*x[3], x[2]^2, x[3]^2)
      })
    ))
) 

#Unpack all inner lists from the expanded matrix
ret_trans <- as.matrix( apply(transformed, 2, function(x) unlist(x)) )
```

EDIT: I add an example of that

```
    dataset
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    6   11
[2,]    2    7   12
[3,]    3    8   13
[4,]    4    9   14
[5,]    5   10   15
```

and on applying the code above I want to expand to N*6, 5*6 (sorry, I misspelled the column dimension up there, and the margin of apply function) it should be like that

```
transformed
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] 1    6    11   66   36   121 
[2,] 2    7    12   84   49   144 
[3,] 3    8    13   104  64   169 
[4,] 4    9    14   126  81   196 
[5,] 5    10   15   150  100  225
```

The question is if there is another way of doing that without having to use the last apply function, without having to coerce the x to be a list
thanks all for your replies

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you do `x[2]%*%x[3]`. You are just multiplying two scalars. Why not use `x[2]*x[3]`?

Comment: isn't your original matrix N*3 and not N*2 like you say? Should the `apply`-ed `MARGIN` be `1` and not `2`? What about you show on a small example what your expected output is? And see if `cbind(x, x[,2]*x[,3], x[,2]^2, x[,3]^2)` does it...

Comment: @flodel & SimonO101 you are both correct, the cross product is a misspell as well as the margin, I'm at the outset of R, so sorry for all the errors

Comment: @DiegoJimenoPrieto keep at it, you'll get there. +1 for providing a reproducible example and taking the time to edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like suggested in the comments, do:

```
cbind(dataset, dataset[,2] * dataset[,3], dataset[,c(2, 3)]^2)
```

It will be a lot faster than using `apply`, which should have looked like this:

```
transformed <- function(x) c(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[2]*x[3], x[2]^2, x[3]^2)
apply(dataset, 1, transformed)
```